# Understanding crystal momentum change in an indirect band gap

Tags: solid-state-physics, momentum, crystals

Is there an intuitive explanation of how the crystal momentum can change to excite an electron from the valence band to the conduction band?

How does a photon change the crystal momentum of an electron to push it up to the conduction band? How does it work on the quantum scale of things?

From what I understand, the photons create wave-like vibrations in the crystalline structure that carry the electron and shift its momentum towards the conduction band? If so, how does a photon achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

In electron transitions due to light absorption/emission in an indirect band-gap semiconductor usually phonons provide the missing momentum to ensure momentum conservation. This is necessary because photons have a large energy but a comparatively small momentum.